# Como tratar exceção em uma Webview?

Tags: java, android, exceção

Queria saber como tratar exceções na minha Webview, pois as vezes o site ta off, e a pagina não carrega, e as vezes ate trava a aplicação. tentei um `try` `catch` no load, mas não entra na exceção, quero que quando o servidor estiver off, ele mande a mensagem, **SERVIDOR INDISPONÍVEL!**

vejam minha Webview:

```
public void carregarSite() {    

    // Verifica conexão
    if (verificaConexao()) { //se tiver conexao
        // Ajusta algumas configurações
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        try{
          wv.loadUrl(URL);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "SERVIDOR INDISPONIVEL!", 1000).show();
        }
    } else           
        msgConexao(); // metodo de msg de conexao
}
```

Comment: Chegou a implementar o método `onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)` do `WebChromeClient`?

Comment: Acredito que basta você implementar e fazer o tratamento do `errorCode` que pode variar conforme o tipo de erro. A lista de erros possíveis está nessa página: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html.

Comment: Eu implementei dessa forma: private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Servidor indisponivel", 1000).show();

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }                             porem sem sucesso

Comment: amigo, tentei essa solução : http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/android-override-default-webview-error.html, porem nada ocorre tbm, como posso prosseguir?

Comment: Realmente, erros de HTTP não são notificados por essa `callback`, de acordo com esse **issue**: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32755. Terá que verificar isso fazendo uma requisição HTTP para descobrir se o servidor responde com status 200...

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de contornar esse problema é utilizando um `WebviewClient` para tratar a recepção de erros:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, int errorCode, String description,final String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "SERVIDOR INDISPONIVEL!", 1000).show();
        }
});
```

O `WebviewClient` fica vinculado ao teu objeto `WebView` e assim permite a implementação do método chamado quando ocorre algum problema no carregamento da url do objeto `WebView`. Dentro dele você pode tratar a exceção amigavelmente para o usuário, utilizando o `Toast`, por exemplo.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221728/handle-network-issues-in-webview.